# Updated laptop keyboard is not working properly

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers, keyboard

last month I dropped some coffe over my laptop's keyboard and it stopped working so I bought a new one (not the exact keyboard but one very similar with the same connector).
But I have a problem, i connected the new laptop keyboard and the computer recognices the keys, but they are not mapped properly, when i press 'A' by example a "/" is written so I was wondering if there is any fix to this problem (downloading other drivers, remapping the keyboard etc...)

This is the keyboard that i have bought: http://www.ebay.es/itm/Teclado-Espanol-para-Msi-S1N-3EUS231-SA0-Version-2-/231893487607?hash=item35fdedcff7:g:sK4AAOSw9uFW-QPo

The old keyboard serial number is Sunrex V139922CK1 SP and the new one is the Sunrex V111922DK1

Comment: Which keyboard?

Comment: @Xavierjazz I had a msi pg60 leopard and i bought this keyboard http://www.ebay.es/itm/Teclado-Espanol-para-Msi-S1N-3EUS231-SA0-Version-2-/231893487607?hash=item35fdedcff7:g:sK4AAOSw9uFW-QPo

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Windows picked a default driver that didn't exactly match up. You can try a couple ways to update the driver:

1) The best way to fix this is IF the keyboard came with driver disc install the drivers off that disc. If not look and the mfg tag on the back of the keyboard and it should give you the make and model and you can pull the driver off the vendors website, assuming its still in production/supported. Then follow the steps in option #2 to install it from the device manager if the drivers aren't self installing.

2) In your windows search bar go to DEVICE MANAGER and look to see if you have a question mark icon. This is a good indicator that windows doesn't know what the device is and needs a driver. If this is the case  on the icon of the device and you should see an option to update the driver. It may be able to find it on the internet without your help.

Hope this helps you get operable, if not reply with your findings.

Comment: The old keyboard serial number is Sunrex V139922CK1 SP and the new one is the Sunrex V111922DK1 ¿Where can I find the drivers? @TechMonk